# Oracle bug related to TO_DATE function?

Tags: oracle11g

I have some month/year data stored in a VARCHAR2 field, formatted as MM/YYYY.
When I try to convert it to a date for comparison with other dates in WHERE clause, I get "ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0" error.

I checked for null values, there are none. I checked the two character month with min and max functions, they return min = '01' and max = '12'.  I checked the separator - there are no rows where position 3 is not '/'.   The length of the field is always 7.  Finally, using 4 characters from the year position, I determined that min = '2010' and max = '3020'.   I also checked each character of the year for < '0' and > '9' with no rows returned.   When I run the SQL without the to_date in the WHERE clause, but leave it in as a select column, then it does not throw an error.

How do I locate the bad data in this case?   I am stumped.

Field null check (in where clause):

```
and field is null ; result is 0 rows
```

Length of field checking (in where clause):

```
and length(field) != 7 ; result is 0 rows
```

Month checking (as select column)

```
min(substr(field, 1, 2)) ; result is '01' (string)
max(substr(field, 1, 2)) ; result is '12' (string)
```

Separator checking (in where clause)

```
and substr(field, 3, 1) != '/'    ; result is 0 rows
```

Year checking (as select column)

```
min(substr(field, 4, 4)) ; result is '2010' (string)
max(substr(field, 4, 4)) ; result is '3020' (string)
```

Comment: 1) Are you passing a format string to `TO_DATE`? 2) Write some code that tests one value at a time, and catches the ORA-01841, printing the value that caused the problem.

Comment: can you post the code you used to check for months, third character, etc.? The approach you took is correct, and if the queries are correct also, then you should have caught the bad data. So let's look at the queries.

Comment: and how do you  convert?

Answer (score 2):

Found my issue - other portions of my WHERE clause were narrowing my focus to the rows with GOOD data.  However, there is no guarantee about the order of which items in the WHERE clause are evaluated first, second, etc.  So I had to look at ALL the data for 'field' in the table.  You cannot just comment out the WHERE clause giving you trouble.  I found some rows with field = '0/0' which was the root cause of my data issue.

Comment: I was starting to wonder if it was doing math 2015/10 then trying to cast 201.5 to a date...

Comment: If you want to find the bad data and to get the exact problem with each invalid string, you can use a CASE expression, which **is** evaluated in order. Do let me know if you need help with this.